# Custom keyboard SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to build a custom keyboard in SwiftUI.

- The UI should look like a decimalPad like keyboard
- On the top of the keyboard where suggestions generally appear, I added a toggle to switch value of keys on the keyboard

```
let numberRows = [
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["4", "5", "6"],
        ["7", "8", "9"],
        ["OK", "0", "Delete"]
    ]

    let alphabeticalRows = [
        ["A", "B", "C"],
        ["D", "E", "F"],
        ["G", "H", "I"],
        ["OK", "J", "Delete"]
    ]
```

Above are the values that should appear in each key.

- "Ok" should dismiss keyboard
- "Delete" Should delete

The final goal is to create a custom TextField to add licence plate in brazilian format

AAA - 0 (numberRows/alphabeticalRows characters) 00

first three a normal keyboard
for the last 4, the custom keyboard I'm trying to build

I tried multiple ways to figure this out. Added a bunch of libraries, used UIkit and even tried to create a keyboard extension. But the closest I got is this:

```
import CustomKeyboardKit
import SwiftUI

class MercosulKeyboardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    @Published var keyboardChanged = false
    @Published var selector = false {
        willSet {
            print("About to set selector to \(newValue)")
        }
    }
    @Published var id = UUID()

    func switchKeyboard() {
        selector.toggle()
    }

    let numberRows = [
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["4", "5", "6"],
        ["7", "8", "9"],
        ["OK", "0", "Delete"]
    ]

    let alphabeticalRows = [
        ["A", "B", "C"],
        ["D", "E", "F"],
        ["G", "H", "I"],
        ["OK", "J", "Delete"]
    ]

    var currentRows: [[String]] {
        if selector == true {
            return numberRows
        }
        else {
            return alphabeticalRows
        }
    }

    var onCharacter: ((String) -> Void) = { _ in }
    var onDelete: (() -> Void) = {}
    var onDismiss: (() -> Void) = {}

    func characterFor(row: Int, column: Int) -> String {
        if selector == true {
            return numberRows[row][column]
        }
        else {
            return alphabeticalRows[row][column]
        }
    }

    func buttonActionForCharacter(_ character: String) {
        if character == "Delete" {
            deleteAction()
        } else if character == "OK" {
            dismissAction()
        } else {
            guard text.count < 4 else { return }
            text += character
            onCharacter(character)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteAction() {
        guard !text.isEmpty else { return }
        text.removeLast()
        onDelete()
    }

    func dismissAction() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

extension CustomKeyboard {
    static func mercosul(viewModel: MercosulKeyboardViewModel) -> CustomKeyboard {
        return CustomKeyboardBuilder { textDocumentProxy, submit, playSystemFeedback in
            viewModel.onCharacter = { character in
                textDocumentProxy.insertText(character)
                playSystemFeedback?()
            }
            viewModel.onDelete = {
                textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
                playSystemFeedback?()
            }
            viewModel.onDismiss = { submit?() }
            
            return VStack {
                
                Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                    get: { viewModel.selector },
                    set: { _ in viewModel.switchKeyboard() }
                )) {
                    Text("Switch to Alphabetical")
                }
                .padding()
                .animation(.default)
                
                ForEach(0..<viewModel.currentRows.count, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                    HStack(spacing:60) {
                        ForEach(0..<viewModel.currentRows[rowIndex].count, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                            let character = viewModel.characterFor(row: rowIndex, column: columnIndex)
                            Button(action: {
                                viewModel.buttonActionForCharacter(character)
                            }) {
                                Text(character)
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.gray)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .id(viewModel.id)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentViews: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MercosulKeyboardViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("type here", text: $viewModel.text)
            .customKeyboard(CustomKeyboard.mercosul(viewModel: viewModel))
    }
}
```

Comment: What *specific* issue do you have with this code?

Comment: Toggle is not changing values for each key and I couldn't adjust the UI yet to look like a default numberPad like keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out my Swift Package [CustomKeyboardKit](https://github.com/paescebu/CustomKeyboardKit)!
I hope i'm not late with the answer.

Indeed you're running into a limitation that I'm still looking into fixing somehow in the future. Rerenders triggered by parent views are not bubbling down into the custom keyboard `View` (yet). But I think i have a - not too shabby - workaround for you:
Simply wrap your keyboard view into a separate SwiftUI `View` and annotate your passed `ViewModel` with `@ObservedObject`.
Your extension would instead look like this:

```swift
extension CustomKeyboard {
    static func mercosul(viewModel: MercosulKeyboardViewModel) -> CustomKeyboard {
        return CustomKeyboardBuilder { textDocumentProxy, submit, playSystemFeedback in
            MercosulKeyboardView(textDocumentProxy: textDocumentProxy, playSystemFeedback: playSystemFeedback, submit: submit, viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
    
    struct MercosulKeyboardView: View {
        var textDocumentProxy: UITextDocumentProxy
        var playSystemFeedback: (() -> Void)? = nil
        var submit: (() -> Void)? = nil

        @ObservedObject var viewModel: MercosulKeyboardViewModel

        var body: some View {
            viewModel.onCharacter = { character in
                textDocumentProxy.insertText(character)
                playSystemFeedback?()
            }
            viewModel.onDelete = {
                textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
                playSystemFeedback?()
            }
            viewModel.onDismiss = { submit?() }
            
            return VStack {
                
                Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                    get: { viewModel.selector },
                    set: { _ in viewModel.switchKeyboard() }
                )) {
                    Text("Switch to Alphabetical")
                }
                .padding()
                .animation(.default)
                
                ForEach(0..<viewModel.currentRows.count, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                    HStack(spacing:60) {
                        ForEach(0..<viewModel.currentRows[rowIndex].count, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                            let character = viewModel.characterFor(row: rowIndex, column: columnIndex)
                            Button(action: {
                                viewModel.buttonActionForCharacter(character)
                            }) {
                                Text(character)
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.gray)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .id(viewModel.id)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I haven't checked the rest of the logic, but I think this way the rest should work as expected as well together with the fixed re-rendering.

In the future don't hesitate to get in touch directly with me on my GitHub Repo! You might have gotten a reply earlier :)

I hope that helps!